# SpriteKit - Side scrolling game - Spawning a random item to continuously fill the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a set of sprite (enemies) which a player needs to avoid as they move past. What is the best way to keep these sprites spawning in the right location throughout the time of the game? The enemies should be in a line and continuously spawn one after the other with no gaps between them, assuming an arbitrary y value, can anyone point me in the right direction to implement this in a SpriteKit game?

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more context. Are you asking how to add a node to the scene? Are you asking how to move a node in the scene? Or how to do either of those things at a fixed interval?

Comment: Use a timer to create your enemy sprites.